# Active Directory - Search By Display Name

Tags: active-directory

Is there a way to search active directory (using DSQUERY or DSGET) to find a user by thier display name?

Answer (score 1):

```
dsquery user -name "Display Name"
```

Will work.

It's not entirely clear (to me anyway) from the question what you are trying to achieve, but that will return a users DN.

I'm not sure what you really mean by "find a user".

Answer (score 0):

**dsquery user -name %1* | dsget user -display -fn -ln -upn**

%1* reemplace for user name,
for example

dsquery user -name victor* | dsget user -display -fn -ln -upn

```
           It show all names contain victor
```

Regards.
Victor.-